# How can I initiate a chat but avoid being a Q&A session?

Tags: friends, chatting

I had a nice zoom chat with my friend yesterday; we are both college students. We haven't met each other for a while and we were both excited to share some updates of our lives.

However, after the meeting, I realized that our chat was like a Q&A session. I asked him for some information about his university and the programs he is attending (because I initiated the chat).

But I feel like we could be more interactive and discuss something even deeper, but I didn't know how to transit to a deeper talk from just short Q&As, especially in a video chat since we're living at different cities.

**How can I initiate a chat but avoid being a Q&A session?**

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/26459/1599), which also focuses on moving conversations beyond small talk. Do the answers there help? If not, are there things in there you've tried that didn't work? Have you ever had a deeper conversation with someone, and how did that happen? Can you explain why you think that approach won't work here?